# read from file and write some parts in another file

Tags: java, formatted-input

I have to read from a text file and format the input. I'm new to java reading from files, and I don't know how to work with just some parts of what I read
Here is the initial file: http://pastebin.com/D0paWtAd

And I have to write in another file the following output:
Average,Joe,44,31,18,12,9,10

I've managed just to take everything from the file and print it to output. I would need help just in taking the output I need and print it to the screen. Any help is appreciated.

This is what I wrote up to now:

```
public class FileParsing {
public static String

read(String filename) throws IOException {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Bogdi\\Desktop\\example.txt"));

String s;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((s = in.readLine())!= null)   sb.append(s + "\n");

in.close();

return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to do the specified output in another file you don't need to first get the content of your file in a StringBuilder before processing it, you can append the processed datas directly in a StringBuilder then you can write the result in a file. Here is an example that would work for the given file but you may have to modify it if the keys change in the future:

The following method will correctly process the datas from your file

```
public static String read(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    String s;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((s = in.readLine())!= null) {
        String[] split1 = s.split("=");

        if (split1[0].equals("name")) {

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(split1[1]);
            sb.append(tokenizer.nextToken());
            sb.append(",");

            sb.append(tokenizer.nextToken());
            sb.append(",");


        } else if (split1[0].equals("index")) {

            sb.append(split1[1] + ",");

        } else if (split1[0].equals("FBid")) {
            sb.append(split1[1]);

        } else {

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(split1[1]);
            String wasted = tokenizer.nextToken();

            sb.append(tokenizer.nextToken() + ",");

        }

    }

    in.close();

    return sb.toString();
}
```

The next method will read any string to a file

```
public static void writeStringToFile(String string, String  filePath) throws IOException {

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter(
                    new File(filePath)
                    )
            );

    writer.write(string);

    writer.newLine();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

}
```

And here is a simple tests (File1.txt contains the datas from the file you shared on paste bin and I write them in another file)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String datas = read("C:\\Tests\\File1.txt");
    System.out.println(datas);

    writeStringToFile(datas, "C:\\Tests\\FileOuput.txt" );


}
```

It will produce the exact output that you are expecting

**[EDIT]** @idk, apparently you have an exception executing my example, while it is working fine for me. That could only mean there is an error at data level. Here is the data sample that I used (and I believe I exactly copy the datas you shared)

[image: datas file]

And here is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: Good complete answere you could use: 
`Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` 
for a much more compact writer.

Comment: I gen an error when I run it. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at gdf.Something.FileParsing(FileParsing.java:38)
 at gdf.Main.main(Main.java:5)
Any suggestion?

Comment: the error refers to this line of code:              StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(split1[1]);

Comment: @Idk I have no errors according to the datas that I took from the link that you shared.

Comment: @idk I just posted the datas I used as well as the result. I still have no errors. Have you updated the datas since your first publication? Best wishes.

Comment: @alainlompo I've corrected the error. In my example there were new lines between the datas. Sorry, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @idk you are most welcome! Looking forward for another opportunity to `java` with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Good to know you are using "StringBuilder" component instead being concatenating your String values, way to go :).

More than knowledge on the Java.IO API to work with files, you will need some logic to get the results you expect. Here I came with an approach that could help you, not perfect, but can point you on how to face this problem.

```
//Reference to your file
    String myFilePath = "c:/dev/myFile.txt";
    File myFile = new File(myFilePath);

    //Create a buffered reader, which is a good start
    BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
    //Define this variable called line that will evaluate each line of our file
    String line = null;
    //I will use a StringBuilder to append the information I need
    StringBuilder appender = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = breader.readLine()) != null) {
        //First, I will obtain the characters after "equals" sign
        String afterEquals = line.substring(line.indexOf("=") + 1, line.length());

        //Then, if it contains digits...
        if (afterEquals.matches(".*\\d+.*")) {
            //I will just get the digits from the line
            afterEquals = afterEquals.replaceAll("\\D+","");
        }

        //Finally, append the contents
        appender.append(afterEquals);
        appender.append(",");//This is the comma you want to include
    }

    //I will delete the last comma
    appender.deleteCharAt(appender.length() - 1);

    //Close the reader...
    breader.close();

    //Then create a process to write the content
    BufferedWriter myWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("myResultFile.txt")));
    //Write the full contents I get from my appender :)
    myWriter.write(appender.toString());
    //Close the writer
    myWriter.close();
}
```

Hope this can help you. Happy coding!